# PHP 7.0 package not foung in ppa:ondrej/php

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, apt-get

I'm having some trouble installing PHP 7.2 on my Ubuntu box.
The Ubuntu disribution i use is Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS / trusty which I installed using Vagrant.

As written on nearly every website, I've added the ppa:ondrej/php repo by doing the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then, I tried installing PHP 7.2:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2
```

The problem seems to be that the PHP 7.2 package is somehow not available, since

```
apt-cache search php
```

only lists the php5-... components.

What could be causing this problem and how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance,
fabianst.

Comment: Thanks for that, upgraded to a higher version (bionic) and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Although the PPA supports Ubuntu 14.04 the specific software version you're looking for isn't available for that release.

Also 14.04 is End of Life, unsupported and shouldn't be used.

Upgrading to the current LTS release allowed the installation of the desired version from the same PPA.